# WCF Data Service Customize XML

Tags: wcf-data-services

Created a WCF data service and got everything working, but the xml is not formatted quite the way I need and I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of all the extra stuff. What I have is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry xml:base="http://172.1.2.2/Database/DatabaseTables.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<id>http://172.1.2.2/Database/DatabaseTables.svc/Device('999')</id>
<title type="text"></title>
<updated>2013-05-14T18:17:10Z</updated>
<author>
  <name />
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="Device" href="Device('999')" />
<category term="Model.Device" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
<content type="application/xml">
  <m:properties>
    <d:Device_Code>999</d:Device_Code>
    <d:Short_name>TC2</d:Short_name>
  </m:properties>
 </content>
</entry>
```

What I want is:

```
<Device>
  <Device_Code>999</Device_Code>
  <Short_name>TC2</Short_name>
</Device>
```

I have already added the name attribute to the data contract but it did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

WCF Data Services produces [OData](http://www.odata.org), which is a uniform protocol built on the common traits of RESTful services. Using OData means that people consuming your service don't need to learn server-specific details of your custom API in order to understand the payload format, URI conventions, and HTTP method semantics. If they already understand OData, and your service produces OData, they don't need to learn anything new or write lots of custom code.

The xml that you want to send back is not formatted in one of the OData payload formats. That's not a problem per-se, but you should be aware that you won't be able to use the WCF Data Services client (aka "Add Service Reference" in Visual Studio), PowerPivot, or any of the other tools and client libraries that understand OData. In addition, the OData xml format is built on top of AtomPub, which means that most browsers (and other Atom-readers) can display the data in an intelligent way.

If you're looking to create a custom REST API using your own format, there might be other libraries and frameworks out there which would be better suited. [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) might be a good choice here.  I'm not sure about this, but I think Web API might also make it possible for you to use the standard OData URI conventions ($filter, $select, etc.) while producing a custom format.

To summarize: OData is great if you want to stick to a common standard and want to be able to rely on existing, well-tested libraries to consume your service. WCF Data Services is a very solid and stable implementation of OData. But if you're not using OData (or if you're only using parts of it), WCF Data Services is probably not going to be what you're looking for.

Comment: So there is no way to control the format of the payload itself from WCF? All I need is the above format so that it can easily autoload into a class on the other end. The current XML is making that a nightmare. There has to be some way to override this behavior and create the output required. I don't need to reference it in visual studio or have a browser display it. I need to be able to format the output exactly with no extra data.

Comment: I don't know of a straightforward way to do this in WCF Data Services (with just WCF there might be however, I'm not very knowledgeable about WCF). Can I ask why you're using WCF data services?